# 4-20 mA Loop voltage Implementation using XTR115

Tags: 4-20ma

I want to Implement 4-20mA current loop using this circuit that is proposed in the IC datasheet.
[image]

I used 7805 regulator to Implement Vloop and this is my Schematics.
will this work?
Edit: the load is an 180 ohm coil.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I used 7805 regulator to Implement Vloop and this is my Schematics.
>   will this work?*

No, it will fail miserably. The XTR115 has an internal 5 volt regulator and so it will expect \$V_{LOOP}\$ to be significantly higher than 5 volt and probably in the region of 10 to 30 volts (without checking).

OK I've just checked and it needs to be at least 7.5 volts and typically is 24 volts: -

[image]

Comment: So if I replace the 7805 with a 7809 it will work ?

Comment: Yes it should work if the load resistor is resistive - you said it was a 180 ohm coil and it will have inductance and the circuit may do odd things like "go-unstable" or develop faults due to back-emfs from the inductor. Or it may just be fine.